# android Static Initialization opencv 3.0 Cannot load library "opencv_java3"

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-ndk

Using `Android ADT` am trying to static initialize openCV so it included in the app build and users don't have to download openCV Manager from the Android playstore.

Am using openCV v3 (http://opencv.org/downloads.html)

At the stage just trying to add static initialization to one of the samples in OpenCV-android-sdk\samples\face-detection.

I have followed the example (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)

Looked at lots of examples but as yet come up with no solution to getting it working. Very much hope someone might be able to help.

I did think might be due to libopencv_java3.so not being in the folder `libs/armeabi-v7a/` When i copy and paste it from `OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs\armeabi-v7a` it disappears. I believe this could be something to do with the way the ndk is setup.  Of course the issue could be something completely different.

LogCat gives this:

```
11-26 16:36:33.647: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(13993): Trying to load library opencv_java3 
11-26 16:36:33.647: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(13993): Cannot load library "opencv_java3" 
11-26 16:36:33.647: W/System.err(13993): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java3 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null 
11-26 16:36:33.767: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(13993): Trying to load library opencv_java3 
11-26 16:36:33.767: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(13993): Cannot load library "opencv_java3" 
11-26 16:36:33.767: W/System.err(13993): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java3 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Comment: Managed to fix it. Am posting this comment in the hope it might help other people with the same issue.  In jni/Android.mk changed the line from #OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on to override OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on This then added libopencv_java3.so to libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so

Answer (score 16):

incase someone comes across this issue and uses AndroidStudio. You can fix it by simply copying the folder OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs

into your OpenCvProject/openCVLibrary310/source/main and rename it to jniLibs. So that the final structure looks like this:
OpenCvProject/openCVLibrary310/source/main/jniLibs/
[image]

If you already ran your project out of AndroidStudio make sure to delete it first from the device. Otherwise AndroidStudio might not redeploy it and because of that might not copy over the libs.

It might also work if you copy the libs into your actual project and not into the openCVLibrary folder but I didn't try that.

Comment: this is resulting in a 90+ MB apk file. _Possibly because its compiled for all platforms_?

Comment: yes, need to add [splits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42019169/3125070) in gradle

Comment: thanks a lot. I put my jniLibs in the java folder :(

Comment: Superlike to this

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran possibly yes, but you could remove the platforms you are not targeting. Most of the time you would need x86 or x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the option to install modules set to "ON" before including Opencv.mk:

```
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include ${OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK}/${ANDROID_SDK_JNI}/OpenCV.mk
```

I already set my variables in my makefile

see:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this problem for hours, when I tried something just for fun and VOILÁ! I got the problem on `System.loadLibrary("whateverYourLibraryWasCalled");` so I add loaded OpenCV just before:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
    System.loadLibrary("MyOpencvLibs");
}
```

And everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I meet with this question recently!
Because I don‘t put the so into the folder "app/src/main/jniLibs" but to the folder "app/src/main/cpp/libs"(custom)

**Folder path:**

[image: folder path]

**Runtime error:**

[image: runtime error]

APK content:

[image: apk content]

we can see, `libopencv_java3.so` not packed to apk file.

I modified  'so' folder path to "app/src/main/jniLibs" and modified "CMakeLists.txt".

**Use jniLibs:**

[image: use jniLibs]

and build project.

we can see.

[image: apk content]

we can find `libopencv_java3.so`.

and app run normally.

so I think we should put all 'so' files to jniLibs folder.

If you want to use other folder. you should config in your "build.gradle"

Comment: What you are saying is all true and details what I wrote in my answer. Thanks for the details :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is

```
android {
 .....

    defaultConfig {
      .....
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope fully it also worked for you.

cheer!