# How to reduce the apk size of my Android app with openCv library integrated

Tags: android, opencv, apk

I have searched for this a lot, but didn't get a solution and hence posting this.

**Scenario:** I'm building an Android app which uses opencv library. When I build the APK file the size of apk is '66' MB which is too much for my app.I'm using the latest version of OpenCV

**Analysis :** When I analyze the apk file, I could see that the size is too big due to 'libopencv_java3.so' file in all architectures like amr64, armeabi, mips, x86 etc. If I remove all those files and build APK, then the size is 7 MB only, which can work only with OpenCVManager installed in the target device

**Problem :** I don't want my app users to install another app (OpenCVManager) to run my app. So, just want to know, what all are the possible solutions to reduce the apk size of the app to work without the help of OpenCVManager ?

Comment: Did you find any better solution ? If yes, please share it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enable ABI splitting in the build.gradle file like this:

```
    android {
    // Some other configuration here...

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}
```

Refer this link https://realm.io/news/reducing-apk-size-native-libraries/

Comment: I think ABI splitting is not needed if we are using android app bundle right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use proguard to obfuscate, minify, shrink resources. Just make sure to read docs by OpenCV for their proguard rules, Run android lint for unused resources.